# Xhtml and Divs/Floating

Tags: xhtml, css-float, html

I am trying to place two divs next to each-other on the same line, have a break and then have another full block div.

Here is what I have so far
body code

```
<body>
    <div class="noFloat">
        <div class="square bgBlue ltFloat">I'm Blue</div>
        <div class="square bgGreen ltFloat">I'm Green</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="dvCenter">I'm in the middle</div>
    <div class="dvCenter">I'm in the middle</div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bgBlue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.bgGreen {
    background-color: green;
}
.dvCenter {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: purple;
}
.ltFloat
{
    float: left;
}
.noFloat
{
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

I am very stuck as to why this won't work correctly.  Any help is greatly appreciated :-)
By break I intended to have the two left floated divs sharing no horizontal space with the centered divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.noFloat` rule to

```
.noFloat
{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    overflow:auto;
    clear:both;
}
```

**demo** at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/53vVP/1

---

Alternatively you can set `clear:left;` on the `.dvCenter` rule.

**demo** at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/53vVP/

---